# Undefine Method in Laravel-5?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

Please can anybody tell me how can i fix this error.I'm new in the laravel so i cannot understand the methods. Please help me to fix this error.

> undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::edit()

Please help me or tell me why this error came up.

Comment: Please write some code here.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758158/upgrading-to-laravel-5-3-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-bu?rq=1

Comment: public function viewCv($id) {$user=Applicants::where('id',$id)->first();if($user->cvUrl != ""){return response()->file(storage_path('app/'.$user->cvUrl));}else{return redirect('home')->with('status','Resume not Found.');}}public function edit($id){$applicant = Applicants::find($id);$applicant->edit();return redirect('home')->with('status','Employee Edited');}public function delete($id){$applicant = Applicants::find($id);$applicant->delete();return redirect('home')->with('status','Employee Deleted.');}}

Comment: Please add the code to your question, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

You try function update.
In Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder have function

```
/**
 * Update a record in the database.
 *
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return int
 */
public function update(array $values)
{
    $sql = $this->grammar->compileUpdate($this, $values);

    return $this->connection->update($sql, $this->cleanBindings(
        $this->grammar->prepareBindingsForUpdate($this->bindings, $values)
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple update method example:

```
Route('/update/profile/{id}','UserController@updateData');

public function updateData(Request $request){

   $value = ModelName::find($request->id);
   $value->name = $request->name;
   $value->email = $request->email;
   $value->nickaname = $request->nickaname;
   $value->save();
}
```